# Permission denied to /bin/ when using tcsh with user account

Tags: centos6, tcsh

I am trying to source .my_script from a /home/username/working_directory using tcsh shell:

```
source ./.my_script
```

I get the following errors:

```
UK_PATH=/usr/local/dir_name/UKernel/5.0:.:/home/username:/usr/local/dir_name: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
UPRJDIR=/home/username/working_directory: Command not found.
export: Command not found.
/bin/.: Permission denied.
/bin/.: Permission denied.
```

The fragment of the script that I think gives errors:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f 
#
#

### Script fragment:
set UK_REF = UKernel/5.0
setenv UKERNEL_ROOT /usr/local/dir_name/${UK_REF}
setenv UK_PATH ${UKERNEL_ROOT}:.:${HOME}:/usr/local/dir_name
set path = ($UKERNEL_ROOT/bin $path)
setenv UPRJDIR $cwd;
```

The server is running CentOS 6. When I am using ADMIN account it is getting sourced without any errors. I tried to add my user account to the same groups as ADMIN, but I still getting the same errors.
As it can be seen, the error in lines where my ~HOME directory is referenced. I tried to sudo chmod 755 and 777 my ~HOME directory and all the directories inside or execute script with sudo, but still got this error.

I want find out why I cant source my script using my user account, even if permissions seems to be right

Comment: Maybe your `HOME` environment variable is set with `~` ? (you cannot use `~` with  `setenv` _in tcsh_)

Comment: echo $HOME gives absolute path, /home/username

Comment: Post your findings as an answer to this question, it may be of some use for others.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem and solution: some another script was using these variables later, but it also was reading the $SHELL and tried to source them using a default shell for a user. So default shell for my user account was bash and it gave errors, because it tried to use EXPORT command from within tcsh script, but ADMIN account used tcsh as a default shell, so it gave no errors.

To sum up: check if you script might be calling $SHELL (default shell for a user, not the current shell) variable to figure out which shell commands to use. And if needed, change the default shell for your user account